# Does the Gigabyte GTX 960 graphics card support DisplayPort dual mode DP++?

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi, displayport

I currently run three DVI-D monitors on an aging Radeon 5770HD. Two monitors are plugged into the HD5770 and the third is plugged into the motherboard graphics port.   I have 3 monitors mostly for productivity, I only run games on a single monitor.

I would now like to upgrade to a more powerful card such as the mini Gigabyte GTX 960. I have a micro-atx case and I am using Blender that has better support for nVidia cards for GPU rendering.  Card info:  http://www.gigabyte.com.au/products/product-page.aspx?pid=5369#ov

[image]
However it only has the 2 DVI sockets. So I would need to buy either a HDMI/DVI or DisplayPort/DVI adapter in order to use the 3rd screen.

I believe I can only buy passive DisplayPort adapter if the graphics card supports DP++ (DisplayPort dual mode).

Nowhere on the linked specs page is this mentioned and the so called useless "manual" pdf is a just generic for all Gigabyte "VGA" cards.

If a HDMI to DVI adapter would be a better option, I don't mind, I just need clarity on what sort of adapter I really need.

(I realise I could email Gigabyte, but I've waited weeks for a response when I did that once in the past.  I also hope someone either has tried 3 DVI monitors on a similar/same card or has information that all new cards support DP++.)

Comment: To the downvoter and person who vote to close: This question shows research effort, it is clear and is obviously useful to me.  It would also be useful to anyone else who has DVI monitors and wants to upgrade their graphics card.  If this type of question cannot be asked here, superuser.com is truly stuffed. (It does seem much quieter then a few years ago, maybe this is why).

Comment: I didn't downvote or vote to close, but your question takes the long way around, with a lot of extraneous information, and the exact question isn't clear.  This might get a better reception if you edit it to get right to the point and focus on the core technical question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the DisplayPort you will need an active adapter for this card. Also as far as I know it won't work with 3 monitors unless you are using DisplayPort. For example 2DVI+1HDMI(Or HDMI-DVI adapter) I don't think actually works. It is a requirement to use the active DisplayPort adapter.